# Check if float is an integer: is_integer() vs. modulo 1

Tags: python

I've seen a number of questions asking how to check if a float is an integer. Majority of answers seem to recommend using `is_integer()`:

```
(1.0).is_integer()
(1.55).is_integer()
```

I have also occasionally seen `math.floor()` being used:

```
import math
1.0 == math.floor(1.0)
1.55 == math.floor(1.55)
```

I'm wondering why `% 1` is rarely used or recommended?

```
1.0 % 1 == 0
1.55 % 1 == 0
```

Is there a problem with using modulo for this purpose? Are there edge cases that this doesn't catch? Performance issues for really large numbers?

If `% 1` is a fine alternative, then I'm also wondering why `is_integer()` was introduced to the standard library?

It seems that `%` is much more flexible. For example, its common to use `% 2` to check if a number is odd/even, or `% n` to check if something is a multiple of `n`. Given this flexibility, why introduce a new method (`is_integer`) that does the same thing, or use `math.floor`, both of which require knowing/remembering that they exist and knowing how to use them? I know that `math.floor` has uses beyond just integer checking but still...

Comment: Readability and obviousness…?!

Comment: May I suggest you remove the subjective questions, like "why isn't it used more often?" Whether there's a technical difference between `%` and `is_integer` is answerable, the other stuff not so much.

Comment: just to add a bit of information: `is_integer` uses `o = (floor(x) == x) ? Py_True : Py_False;` (as seen [in the source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/floatobject.c#L833)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All are valid for the purpose. The `math.floor` option requires exact matching between a specific value and the result of the floor function. Which is not very convenient if you want to encapsulate it in a generic method. So it boils down to the first and third option. Both are valid and will do the job. So the key difference is simple - performance:

```
from timeit import Timer

def with_isint(num):
    return num.is_integer()
def with_mod(num):
    return num % 1 == 0

Timer(lambda: with_isint(10.0)).timeit(number=10000000)
#output: 2.0617980659008026
Timer(lambda: with_mod(10.0)).timeit(number=10000000)
#output: 2.6560597440693527
```

Naturally this is a simple operation so you'd need a lot of calls in order to see a considerable difference, as you can see in the example.

Comment: this is a little surprising to me. The difference isn't that big, but `is_integer` has the overhead of a few function calls and yet is faster. any idea what `%` is doing that makes it slower?

Comment: @Simon well in the modulo function you are basically doing two operations, that is, modulo and then compare the result to another integer. `is_integer` is pushed a bit closer to a the metal as you can see [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/floatobject.c#L833)

Answer (score 2):

One soft reason is definitely: readability

If a function called `is_integer()` returns `True`, it is obvious what you have been testing.

However, using the modulo solution, one has to think through the process to see, that it is actually testing if a float is an integer. If you wrap your modulo formalism in a function with an obvious name such as `simon_says_its_an_integer()`, I think it's just as fine (apart from needlessly introducing an already existing function).